# How can I reduce deployment time for web applications on Liberty for Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud-tools

Liberty on developer laptops take under 5 seconds to publish most changes, and negligible time to publish static content changes.

When I publish the changes onto Bluemix Liberty, using "cf push", the deployment takes time in order of minutes. Binary Upload time is still very small. This is true for Node.js apps too.

Increased deployment time discourages developers from testing their changes in cloud environment.

What can I do to reduce the deployment time?

Comment: For Java apps check out [incremental publish](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#incrementalpublish) and for Node.js apps checkout out [live sync](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/bluemixlive.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to consider the following:

1) Use the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix

2) Use **Incremental Push** and **Development Mode**

You can find more info on both of these topics by reviewing the article below:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html